# ViewDataFactory and strongly typed master pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

Im trying to get my strongly typed master page to work in my ASP MVC 2.0 application.
I have come far with the help of these two posts:

[Passing data to Master Page in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78548/passing-data-to-master-page-in-asp-net-mvc/746011#746011)

[Strongly Typed ASP.Net MVC Master Pages](http://www.matthewlowrance.com/matthewlowrance/post/2009/11/11/Strongly-Typed-ASPNet-MVC-Master-Pages.aspx)

Problem is that im not sure how to get that ViewDataFactory code to work, this is my code:

**BaseController.cs**

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{        
    private IPageRepository _repPage;

    public BaseController(IPageRepository repPage)
    {
        _repPage = repPage;
    }

    protected T CreateViewData<T>() where T : MasterViewData, new()
    {
        IViewDataFactory factory = new ViewDataFactory();

        IEnumerable<Page> pages = _repPage.GetAllPages();

        return factory.Create<T>(pages);
    }
}
```

**HomeController.cs**

```
public class HomeController : BaseController
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        HomeViewData viewData = CreateViewData<HomeViewData>();

        viewData.Name = "Test";

        return View("Index", viewData);
    }

    public ActionResult About()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

**ViewDataFactory.cs**

```
public interface IViewDataFactory
{
    T Create<T>(IEnumerable<Page> pages) where T : MasterViewData, new()
}

public class ViewDataFactory : IViewDataFactory
{
    public ViewDataFactory()
    {
    }  
}
```

**HomeViewData.cs**

```
public class HomeViewData : MasterViewData
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**MasterViewData**

```
public class MasterViewData
{
    public IEnumerable<Page> Pages { get; set; }
}
```

When I build the solution I get the follwing build error:

```
"; expected" in ViewDataFactory.cs
```

Which points to the code snippet:

```
T Create<T>(IEnumerable<Page> pages) where T : MasterViewData, new()
```

I guess im missing something essential, im new to this and any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I been digging around looking for an answer to how I can render views inside my master page. All I have found so far is solutions that look like well engineer hacks to a very necessary problem. The more I use ASP.net MVC the more gotchas I find, whats next?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why don't you just add a semicolon at the end of that line? :)

Abstract methods (as well as interface methods) have a semicolon in place of a body.

Comment: Wish it was that easy, when I do that I get another build error:
'Website.Models.ViewDataFactory' does not implement interface member 'Website.Models.IViewDataFactory.Create<T>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Website.Models.Page>)'

Comment: That's because it really doesn't, I assume you're using Visual Studio, if that's the case, right click on the `IViewDataFactory` in the `ViewDataFactory` class declaration, and select `Implement Interface`

Comment: Thank you, it solved my problem so far. But what shall I put inside of the implemented interface. The solution builds as it should but I get an error while running it. `The method or operation is not implemented.` That is because I still have the `throw new NotImplementedException();` inside of it, but what shall I put inside?

Comment: Well, I know virtually nothing about MVC, the syntax error caught my attention, but I can't help you with the actual issue.

Comment: Well thank you so far, you solved my problem. I will keep it open a while more to maybe get some more help and then I will tag it as answered.

Answer (score 1):

I finally got it working thanks to [Aviad P.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1989927/viewdatafactory-and-strongly-typed-master-pages/1989932#1989932)'s suggestions and some trial and error.

This is how my `IViewDataFactory` ended up looking like:

```
public interface IViewDataFactory
{
    T Create<T>(IEnumerable<Page> pages) where T : MasterViewData, new();
}

public class ViewDataFactory : IViewDataFactory
{        
    public T Create<T>(IEnumerable<Page> pages) where T : MasterViewData, new()
    {
        T t = new T();
        t.Pages = pages;
        return t;
    }
}
```