# Html.RenderAction causes "No route in the route table matches the supplied values"

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to use Html.RenderAction in ASP.NET MVC 2 RC2 in this way:

In Menu Controler:

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult ContentPageMenus()
{
     var menus = _contentPageMenuRepository.GetAll().WithCulture(CurrentCulture);
     return PartialView(menus);
}
```

And in my Index view (for Index action of Home controller):

```
 <% Html.RenderAction("ContentPageMenus", "ContentPageMenu");%>
```

But I always get this error message: 
No route in the route table matches the supplied values.

Answer (score 14):

Adding a third parameter like this was the solution for me (in razor):

`@{Html.RenderAction("ActionName", "ControllerName", new { area = string.Empty });}`

Comment: Memet - Can you please let me know whether this solution is fine or not and it won't affect at any other place? -- This does solved my problem

Answer (score 11):

MVC Futures used to allow rendering of actions that had no routes. This has changed in ASP.NET MVC2.

If you want RenderAction to work and would like to hide your route so its not publicly accessible.

1. Add a route for your action in `globals.asax.cs`.
2. Decorate your action with the `[ChildActionOnly]` attribute.

Answer (score 6):

What is your controller's name?
By default the following is what happens with your routes.

The Controller name specified in your RenderAction method is searched for with "Controller" appended to that name.

The Action method in that Controller gets called and a View returned.

So, by looking at your code, the following will happen

1. You should have a Controller called "ContentPageMenuController"
2. You should have an Action called "ContentPageMenus" which you have
3. You should have a view called ContentPageMenus()

This is assuming that you haven't changed the defaulting routing and haven't added new ones that will affect your routing

Comment: I found the problem. I always remove {controller}/{action} route and customize all my routes with lowercase REST like URLs. But for Html.RenderAction it is necessary to have such general route. I added that general route to the end of my routes list and it worked.

Comment: Wow! It took me hours to figure out why I had the error message as stated in the title of this question. The comment here helped me solved it! thanks!

Comment: I use the AttributeRouting project, and it would be great if there was a way to do away with the default route but still have RenderAction work properly! Otherwise I occasionally get burned by a mistyped ActionLink helper resulting in a bad URL based on the default, where I would really prefer an exception!

Answer (score 6):

I had the same error. It was caused by altering the default route; apparently it explicitly searches for a route name "Default".

Answer (score 0):

Have you registered any additional routes for you application?

Comment: I found the problem. I always remove {controller}/{action} route and customize all my routes with lowercase REST like URLs. But for Html.RenderAction it is necessary to have such general route. I added that general route to the end of my routes list and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try using the strong typed method?

Try this:

```
<% Html.RenderAction<ContentPageMenusController>(x => x.ContentPageMenus()); %>
```

You have to fill the exactly name of the class.

Comment: Is it available in ASP.NET MVC 2 RC2? I can't see this.

Comment: It appears that this method is actually from MVC Futures: http://forums.asp.net/p/1565646/3901280.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I have had this issue before, it was where the route didn't include the controller.

```
            context.MapRoute(
            "Route_default",
            "Stuff/{action}/{id}",
        new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

I still wanted to be able to call an action straight after the Area so i added the following route like so.

```
            context.MapRoute(
            "Route_default",
            "Search/{action}/{id}",
        new { controller = "Search", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        context.MapRoute(
            "Route_Controller",
            "Stuff/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Something", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```