# ASP.NET: How to use contentplaceholder in attribute values without editor/designer errors?

Tags: asp.net

I am using a contentplaceholder control in a master page to allow the content editor to specify the URL of an image used as a background to a div.

```
<div id="content-left-column"
     style="background-image: url('<wc:UrlContentPlaceHolder runat='server' ID='leftContentBackgroundUrl'></wc:UrlContentPlaceHolder>');">
```

The placeholder is referenced on the content page like:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="leftContentBackgroundUrl" runat="server">/img/left-content.jpg</asp:Content>
```

The page renders just fine using this approach.  However, when I look at the content page in source view, the ContentPlaceHolderId attribute value is underlined and there is a warning "Could not find 'leftContentBackgroundUrl' in the current master page or pages."

Design view will not render the content page due to this error.

Is there a way to use ContentPlaceHolder for attribute values such that no errors are reported in the Visual Studio editor and design surface?

*Note.  I am aware of the issues with this approach.  If the content editor puts in spaces, carriage returns or performs a document format in visual studio, the rendered attribute value is broken.  I have created a subclass of ContentPlaceHolder that trims its values and uses ResolveClientUrl to address these issues.  For the sake of discussion I have described the issue which affects a normal ContentPlaceHolder control.

The following stack overflow question addresses the fact that ContentPlaceHolder can be used with attribute values but does not address the design surface issues.
[Why can't I use a ContentPlaceholder inside HTML attributes in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4752023/why-cant-i-use-a-contentplaceholder-inside-html-attributes-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution was inspired by @atticae's response.

On the master page, I included a normal ContentPlaceholder control with visible="false".  Where I was previously using that ContentPlaceholder as an attribute value, I instead reference a property of the MasterPage, LeftBackgroundImageUrl.

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat='server' ID='leftContentBackgroundUrl' Visible="false"/>        
<div id="content-left-column" style="background-image: url('<%: LeftBackgroundImageUrl%>');">
```

Using a subclass of ContentPlaceholder causes errors in the design surface of content pages which is why I went back to using a normal ContentPlaceholder.

The LeftBackgroundImageUrl property code looks like:

```
ReadOnly Property LeftBackgroundImageUrl As String
    Get
        Return RenderResolvedUrl(leftContentBackgroundUrl)
    End Get
End Property

Private Function RenderedResolvedUrl(control As Control) As String
    Dim visible As Boolean = control.Visible
    control.Visible = True
    Dim result As String = Nothing
    Using writer As New System.IO.StringWriter()
        Using htmlWriter As New System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(writer)
            control.RenderControl(htmlWriter)
            htmlWriter.Flush()
        End Using
        result = Page.ResolveClientUrl(writer.ToString.Trim).Trim
    End Using
    control.Visible = visible
    Return result
End Function
```

This solution allows the image url to be specified declaratively, and without the user having to add a MasterType directive.  This is not perfect in the sense that it does not, at edit/design time, validate that the content the editor provides is just a URL or application relative URL.  But, it does keep the user from having to write code.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe that's how ContentPlaceHolders where meant to be used. I would strongly advise you to use inline code for this.

Main.master:

```
<div id="content-left-column"
     style="background-image: url(<%: LeftContentBackgroundURL %>);">
```

Main.master.cs:

```
public string LeftContentBackgroundURL { get; set; }
```

In the ContentPage you then just use the [@MasterType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms228274(v=vs.100).aspx) directive and set the Property in Codebehind.

Content.aspx:

```
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/Main.master" %>
```

Content.aspx.cs:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Master.LeftContentBackgroundURL = "/img/left-content.jpg";
}
```

Comment: I want to thank you for taking the time to provide an answer that was specific to my question and providing the inspiration for the solution which I have posted. I'm conflicted because I want to give you credit for taking the time to answer the question but the real answer is what I have posted. Which do you think should be marked as the answer?  In either case, I +1'd your answer.

Comment: You should accept the answer that you think answers the question best. If that is your own, that's perfectly fine. I'm glad I could help.