# How can I put into masterpage by receive category names from database?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I will put menu into masterpage with entity data model in asp.net mvc.And the names of the menu will be dynamic.So,the names of the menu
will receive from database.the moral of the story,How can I put into masterpage by receive category names from database?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do a base model with the data neede for the master pages, and use it in all pages...

---

see this for details [Passing data to Master Page in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78548/passing-data-to-master-page-in-asp-net-mvc#746011)

Other solution would be to put your menu into a partial view, that way you'd have a normal controller that could return your partial view. see [NerdDinner Step 7: Partials and Master Pages](http://nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Part7.htm)

Comment: @moi_meme- First of all ,thanks for your answer.But, Can you give me a little more detail?

Answer (score 0):

You should make normal MenuController, with some action(for ex. Menu()) and view that renders menu only. in controller, you take values from database, create the model and pass it to the view, and the view renders menu html. In the master page, you just use Html.RenderAction() method and the menu will be drawn in its place on master. The explanation why menuController and menu action should be separate is described in Steven Sanderson's book Professional ASP.NET MVC 2. Idea is simple - with MVC pattern views should carry no application logic - just the view for the user. Menu carries application logic - which menu is selected or highlighted, etc. For details, take a look at that book