# Use viewBag in Master page Asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewbag

I am developing a website using asp.net MVC

I want to show the name of user after he/she logged in the website.

The problem is that `User.Identity.Name` returns user email and I do not want to change that because user name is not unique. And I want to access email in other pages.

I like to use a viewBag in my master page, but I do not know where to define it.

If I define it in `Home/controller`, it works just for this action.

Should I use filter?

Answer (score 1):

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78548/passing-data-to-master-page-in-asp-net-mvc) will help you with the problem of passing data to master page.

[This](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/passing-data-to-view-master-pages-cs) is the "official" way to handle that, it explains in a very clear way, but I strongly recommend to read the first link completly too.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using MVC, then I would **strongly** suggest moving to a ViewModel pattern to accomplish this, rather than stuffing objects into the ViewBag, mostly for two reasons: 1) Type Safety, and 2) Intellisense support.

In this kind of situation, you would have your MasterPage inherit from a BaseViewModel, and your actions would return derived objects from the BaseViewModel. You can then set data on your view model, and it will be available to the master page when rendering:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage<MyViewModelBase>" %>
```

Alternatively, you could make a 'partial view' that renders just the content you need based on the user's state.